# How to delete nested column in mongodb with laravel?

Tags: mongodb, laravel

I am using Laravel with Mongodb, i have the table structure as following,

```
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("59323b092798db16b4006e33"),
    "contractorId" : "KT0004",
    "worktypeId" : 1,
    "contractorDetails" : [
      [
        "KT0004",
        1,
        "Air Conditioning",
        "Salim"
      ],
      [
        "KT0001",
        2,
        "Carpentry",
        "Ashok kumar"
      ]
    ]
  }
```

I need to delete the first element from the "ContractorDetails" column, i tried with Laravel Delete, Unset, Destroy, but i did not got the solution, anyone suggest me pls?

Answer (score 0):

According to above mentioned description please try executing following update operation in MongoDB shell

```
db.collection.update({},{$unset:{'contractorDetails.0':1}})
```

According to MongoDB documentation

> The $unset operator deletes a particular field

Comment: Can i implement this in Laravel?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jenssegers' mongodb library for Laravel (https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) then you can `pull` that item to remove it from the array:

```
DB::collection('coll')->where('contractorId', 'KT0004')->pull('contractorDetails', $item);
```

You may need to get that item first, as it is doesn't support removing by position.